# OpenSSL cli: how to extract ESSCertID or ESSCertIDv2 from SignerInfo of timestamp token

Tags: openssl, timestamp, asn1

If I have a Timestamp token, then the signing certificate for the token is identified via the ESSCertID (for RFC3161 tokens) or the ESSCertIDv2 (for FC5816) of the signing certificate, which is the SHA-1 (in the case of ESSCertID) or some other hash (in the case of ESSCertIDv2) of the DER encoding of the signing certificate.

Here's the CMS structure of an RFC3161 token:

```
$ openssl cms -inform DER -in token_nocerts.tst -cmsout -print
CMS_ContentInfo:
  contentType: pkcs7-signedData (1.2.840.113549.1.7.2)
  d.signedData:
    version: 3
    digestAlgorithms:
        algorithm: sha512 (2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.3)
        parameter: NULL
    encapContentInfo:
      eContentType: id-smime-ct-TSTInfo (1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.1.4)
      eContent:
        0000 - 30 82 01 75 02 01 01 06-04 2a 03 04 01 30 31   0..u.....*...01
        000f - 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01-65 03 04 02 01 05 00   0...`.H.e......
        001e - 04 20 89 9b a3 d9 f7 77-e2 a7 4b dd 34 30 2b   . .....w..K.40+
        002d - c0 6c b3 f7 a4 6a c1 f5-65 ee 12 8f 79 fd 5d   .l...j..e...y.]
        003c - ab 99 d6 8b 02 03 2d 19-84 18 0f 32 30 32 31   ......-....2021
        004b - 30 32 30 34 31 34 33 30-35 36 5a 01 01 ff 02   0204143056Z....
        005a - 09 00 83 16 8e 99 d6 23-2e fc a0 82 01 11 a4   .......#.......
        0069 - 82 01 0d 30 82 01 09 31-11 30 0f 06 03 55 04   ...0...1.0...U.
        0078 - 0a 13 08 46 72 65 65 20-54 53 41 31 0c 30 0a   ...Free TSA1.0.
        0087 - 06 03 55 04 0b 13 03 54-53 41 31 76 30 74 06   ..U....TSA1v0t.
        0096 - 03 55 04 0d 13 6d 54 68-69 73 20 63 65 72 74   .U...mThis cert
        00a5 - 69 66 69 63 61 74 65 20-64 69 67 69 74 61 6c   ificate digital
        00b4 - 6c 79 20 73 69 67 6e 73-20 64 6f 63 75 6d 65   ly signs docume
        00c3 - 6e 74 73 20 61 6e 64 20-74 69 6d 65 20 73 74   nts and time st
        00d2 - 61 6d 70 20 72 65 71 75-65 73 74 73 20 6d 61   amp requests ma
        00e1 - 64 65 20 75 73 69 6e 67-20 74 68 65 20 66 72   de using the fr
        00f0 - 65 65 74 73 61 2e 6f 72-67 20 6f 6e 6c 69 6e   eetsa.org onlin
        00ff - 65 20 73 65 72 76 69 63-65 73 31 18 30 16 06   e services1.0..
        010e - 03 55 04 03 13 0f 77 77-77 2e 66 72 65 65 74   .U....www.freet
        011d - 73 61 2e 6f 72 67 31 22-30 20 06 09 2a 86 48   sa.org1"0 ..*.H
        012c - 86 f7 0d 01 09 01 16 13-62 75 73 69 6c 65 7a   ........busilez
        013b - 61 73 40 67 6d 61 69 6c-2e 63 6f 6d 31 12 30   as@gmail.com1.0
        014a - 10 06 03 55 04 07 13 09-57 75 65 72 7a 62 75   ...U....Wuerzbu
        0159 - 72 67 31 0b 30 09 06 03-55 04 06 13 02 44 45   rg1.0...U....DE
        0168 - 31 0f 30 0d 06 03 55 04-08 13 06 42 61 79 65   1.0...U....Baye
        0177 - 72 6e                                          rn
    certificates:
      <ABSENT>
    crls:
      <ABSENT>
    signerInfos:
        version: 1
        d.issuerAndSerialNumber:
          issuer: O=Free TSA, OU=Root CA, CN=www.freetsa.org/emailAddress=busilezas@gmail.com, L=Wuerzburg, ST=Bayern, C=DE
          serialNumber: 13972846748170250626
        digestAlgorithm:
          algorithm: sha512 (2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.3)
          parameter: NULL
        signedAttrs:
            object: contentType (1.2.840.113549.1.9.3)
            set:
              OBJECT:id-smime-ct-TSTInfo (1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.1.4)

            object: signingTime (1.2.840.113549.1.9.5)
            set:
              UTCTIME:Feb  4 14:30:56 2021 GMT

            object: id-smime-aa-signingCertificate (1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.12)
            set:
              SEQUENCE:
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  26 cons: SEQUENCE
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=  24 cons:  SEQUENCE
    4:d=2  hl=2 l=  22 cons:   SEQUENCE
    6:d=3  hl=2 l=  20 prim:    OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:916DA3D860ECCA82E34BC59D1793E7E968875F14

            object: messageDigest (1.2.840.113549.1.9.4)
            set:
              OCTET STRING:
                0000 - 4d b9 02 47 cb 66 6e 37-48 c7 56 04 1a   M..G.fn7H.V..
                000d - 77 45 23 95 72 1d 1d e8-62 3e 7b 68 9d   wE#.r...b>{h.
                001a - 58 43 88 64 a7 b3 1b be-bd 56 8e 58 8d   XC.d.....V.X.
                0027 - 8d 12 fe 11 dc 68 89 a5-56 aa bd 00 df   .....h..V....
                0034 - e4 8d f6 3b d8 8e 7d 78-c7 d2 42 a4      ...;..}x..B.
        signatureAlgorithm:
          algorithm: rsaEncryption (1.2.840.113549.1.1.1)
          parameter: NULL
        signature:
          0000 - 62 39 1e b9 0e e3 ab 74-fa 90 46 bd d6 78 bc   b9.....t..F..x.
          000f - 2e d6 a4 3a 7b f4 0e 45-11 ba 16 c0 48 46 5a   ...:{..E....HFZ
          001e - 52 87 c5 3c 9d ae c7 1d-83 dc c8 03 8f 2e 70   R..<..........p
          002d - 2c 4e 1f 6a 4e 5e 64 b7-5d 56 5e cb c9 6f af   ,N.jN^d.]V^..o.
          003c - 17 3d f4 2f c9 a5 b9 5c-d4 a1 03 1f 43 8f a3   .=./...\....C..
          004b - 46 13 62 df 4d f6 cc 48-ad 2c c3 43 85 5e 8c   F.b.M..H.,.C.^.
          005a - 5b da a8 97 8d 3a 06 28-72 56 f3 38 e3 06 ad   [....:.(rV.8...
          0069 - ca 80 28 28 73 3f 9a 6f-ed ba b9 ac ed f4 6f   ..((s?.o......o
          0078 - 69 9e 91 d4 d2 4d 6b 1f-98 53 16 66 d7 50 62   i....Mk..S.f.Pb
          0087 - 96 61 9f 0f f6 bd 94 19-d6 04 c5 7e f9 3c 89   .a.........~.<.
          0096 - 5a 8a d1 a1 05 72 4e 6f-9c 8a a5 ef 6b 36 8d   Z....rNo....k6.
          00a5 - e5 ee 8a e9 11 8b 1c 70-42 c7 32 6d 27 42 fb   .......pB.2m'B.
          00b4 - 99 71 25 ae 66 67 48 58-10 df 4a db 08 08 ea   .q%.fgHX..J....
          00c3 - b1 a0 d5 ca 22 4b 46 ad-12 fd a1 72 91 c4 8b   ...."KF....r...
          00d2 - 21 d2 ff d8 b3 13 7f f8-31 9c 42 f6 b4 ea b1   !.......1.B....
          00e1 - 15 21 8a ed e0 b9 6a 3c-0d 88 03 aa 4a ca f2   .!....j<....J..
          00f0 - 13 59 54 99 0b 19 70 4f-91 0a 7e f7 17 92 70   .YT...pO..~...p
          00ff - dd 0f 54 cc 1e e7 7b 42-d2 fa c2 53 3a 45 5a   ..T...{B...S:EZ
          010e - 45 09 c3 7b b5 34 6d 0b-40 82 72 45 4d eb 60   E..{.4m.@.rEM.`
          011d - 00 57 c8 46 77 23 5b 1c-c0 ff 6b 01 5c 0e 2f   .W.Fw#[...k.\./
          012c - fb 87 b3 e6 42 e5 1b 1d-25 6c c5 43 c4 af b8   ....B...%l.C...
          013b - 9b 51 74 f2 c9 85 d2 54-52 ca b6 4e ac a1 83   .Qt....TR..N...
          014a - 28 80 99 11 d5 ed a0 82-ad cc df 7d 18 a4 2c   (..........}..,
          0159 - 05 79 c0 f9 be 7c 52 1e-33 84 0c a5 ae b4 4e   .y...|R.3.....N
          0168 - 6d 08 ee 68 13 44 35 15-5f e1 3d e5 72 36 72   m..h.D5._.=.r6r
          0177 - 05 8e 4c 4d 7f 0d ce 32-23 5c 16 bc 73 99 e6   ..LM...2#\..s..
          0186 - 68 ea c5 19 e7 4d d7 0f-22 d5 1c 61 ac a8 cf   h....M.."..a...
          0195 - b6 70 49 79 3c 22 1a 90-96 cd 3b fb 11 bb 56   .pIy<"....;...V
          01a4 - 4f 2a 41 a7 5d 61 f4 81-6a 1c ce 2d f9 0c bb   O*A.]a..j..-...
          01b3 - 91 80 7a 9d 9c 61 37 81-e1 77 20 d3 06 56 be   ..z..a7..w ..V.
          01c2 - f3 df 1c 74 47 ee ab 81-7a 03 80 96 95 a0 93   ...tG...z......
          01d1 - 4b f4 e6 b9 a2 f4 8b 2f-25 80 2f c9 b5 a3 99   K....../%./....
          01e0 - 34 e0 ab 8e 2b fb e3 ce-26 91 0a b3 6d af 18   4...+...&...m..
          01ef - 5a d7 a8 7c 3e c6 1c 17-0d e8 30 da df f2 5d   Z..|>.....0...]
          01fe - 51 3b                                          Q;
        unsignedAttrs:
          <ABSENT>
```

looking at the ASN.1 sequence of the token:

```
$ openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in token_nocerts.tst -i
    0:d=0  hl=4 l=1351 cons: SEQUENCE
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=   9 prim:  OBJECT            :pkcs7-signedData
   15:d=1  hl=4 l=1336 cons:  cont [ 0 ]
   19:d=2  hl=4 l=1332 cons:   SEQUENCE
   23:d=3  hl=2 l=   1 prim:    INTEGER           :03
   26:d=3  hl=2 l=  15 cons:    SET
   28:d=4  hl=2 l=  13 cons:     SEQUENCE
   30:d=5  hl=2 l=   9 prim:      OBJECT            :sha512
   41:d=5  hl=2 l=   0 prim:      NULL
   43:d=3  hl=4 l= 398 cons:    SEQUENCE
   47:d=4  hl=2 l=  11 prim:     OBJECT            :id-smime-ct-TSTInfo
   60:d=4  hl=4 l= 381 cons:     cont [ 0 ]
   64:d=5  hl=4 l= 377 prim:      OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]: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
  445:d=3  hl=4 l= 906 cons:    SET
  449:d=4  hl=4 l= 902 cons:     SEQUENCE
  453:d=5  hl=2 l=   1 prim:      INTEGER           :01
  456:d=5  hl=3 l= 163 cons:      SEQUENCE
  459:d=6  hl=3 l= 149 cons:       SEQUENCE
  462:d=7  hl=2 l=  17 cons:        SET
  464:d=8  hl=2 l=  15 cons:         SEQUENCE
  466:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :organizationName
  471:d=9  hl=2 l=   8 prim:          PRINTABLESTRING   :Free TSA
  481:d=7  hl=2 l=  16 cons:        SET
  483:d=8  hl=2 l=  14 cons:         SEQUENCE
  485:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :organizationalUnitName
  490:d=9  hl=2 l=   7 prim:          PRINTABLESTRING   :Root CA
  499:d=7  hl=2 l=  24 cons:        SET
  501:d=8  hl=2 l=  22 cons:         SEQUENCE
  503:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :commonName
  508:d=9  hl=2 l=  15 prim:          PRINTABLESTRING   :www.freetsa.org
  525:d=7  hl=2 l=  34 cons:        SET
  527:d=8  hl=2 l=  32 cons:         SEQUENCE
  529:d=9  hl=2 l=   9 prim:          OBJECT            :emailAddress
  540:d=9  hl=2 l=  19 prim:          IA5STRING         :busilezas@gmail.com
  561:d=7  hl=2 l=  18 cons:        SET
  563:d=8  hl=2 l=  16 cons:         SEQUENCE
  565:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :localityName
  570:d=9  hl=2 l=   9 prim:          PRINTABLESTRING   :Wuerzburg
  581:d=7  hl=2 l=  15 cons:        SET
  583:d=8  hl=2 l=  13 cons:         SEQUENCE
  585:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :stateOrProvinceName
  590:d=9  hl=2 l=   6 prim:          PRINTABLESTRING   :Bayern
  598:d=7  hl=2 l=  11 cons:        SET
  600:d=8  hl=2 l=   9 cons:         SEQUENCE
  602:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :countryName
  607:d=9  hl=2 l=   2 prim:          PRINTABLESTRING   :DE
  611:d=6  hl=2 l=   9 prim:       INTEGER           :C1E986160DA8E982
  622:d=5  hl=2 l=  13 cons:      SEQUENCE
  624:d=6  hl=2 l=   9 prim:       OBJECT            :sha512
  635:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim:       NULL
  637:d=5  hl=3 l= 184 cons:      cont [ 0 ]
  640:d=6  hl=2 l=  26 cons:       SEQUENCE
  642:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 prim:        OBJECT            :contentType
  653:d=7  hl=2 l=  13 cons:        SET
  655:d=8  hl=2 l=  11 prim:         OBJECT            :id-smime-ct-TSTInfo
  668:d=6  hl=2 l=  28 cons:       SEQUENCE
  670:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 prim:        OBJECT            :signingTime
  681:d=7  hl=2 l=  15 cons:        SET
  683:d=8  hl=2 l=  13 prim:         UTCTIME           :210204143056Z
  698:d=6  hl=2 l=  43 cons:       SEQUENCE
  700:d=7  hl=2 l=  11 prim:        OBJECT            :id-smime-aa-signingCertificate
  713:d=7  hl=2 l=  28 cons:        SET
  715:d=8  hl=2 l=  26 cons:         SEQUENCE
  717:d=9  hl=2 l=  24 cons:          SEQUENCE
  719:d=10 hl=2 l=  22 cons:           SEQUENCE
  721:d=11 hl=2 l=  20 prim:            OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:916DA3D860ECCA82E34BC59D1793E7E968875F14
  743:d=6  hl=2 l=  79 cons:       SEQUENCE
  745:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 prim:        OBJECT            :messageDigest
  756:d=7  hl=2 l=  66 cons:        SET
  758:d=8  hl=2 l=  64 prim:         OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:4DB90247CB666E3748C756041A77452395721D1DE8623E7B689D58438864A7B31BBEBD568E588D8D12FE11DC6889A556AABD00DFE48DF63BD88E7D78C7D242A4
  824:d=5  hl=2 l=  13 cons:      SEQUENCE
  826:d=6  hl=2 l=   9 prim:       OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
  837:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim:       NULL
  839:d=5  hl=4 l= 512 prim:      OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]: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
```

it be `916DA3D860ECCA82E34BC59D1793E7E968875F14` (close to the end, at offset 721 in this case)

according to spec (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3161.txt) there is always exactly one SignerInfo and this signerInfo always must contain a ESSCertID (or alternatively a ESSCertIDv2 according to RFC3161 spec https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5816)

using openssl cli, now can I extract this hash?

Comment: This seems to me like this shouldn't be a task for OpenSSL's cli, but rather their library.

Comment: I'm writing a bash script and I'd like to not depend on custom binaries

Comment: What happens if you openssl asn1parse with offset 721?

Comment: @Z.T. that works, but this signature is not always at offset 721, that depends on the token

Comment: Of course. That is why you need to write code, not a bash script.

Comment: but maybe it's possible using cli to find the offset? because in terms of structure, it's always at the same location. token->signedData->SignerInfos[0]->authenticatedAttributes->SigningCertificate(or SigningCertificateV2)->ESSCertID(or ESSCertIDv2)->firstFieldAsOctetString(or second field in case of ESSCertIDv2)

I thought maybe it's possible to retrieve the offset using this? maybe somehow using the (undocumented) -item parameter? or if it would be possible to parse out the length of the structure at a certain offset, probably that could be used too

Comment: or maybe it's possible with openssl cli to somehow sarch for a specific OID and extract that?